# check app settings using userDefaults in iOS using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

How do I check what the user sets app settings to?  I think I'm supposed to be able to use UserDefaults to do this.  I particularly want to check whether the user has allowed the app to access Contacts.  I know how to get the setting if I knew the key.  I would like to be able to access all the settings that UserDefaults have for the app.  I am using Swift to create an iOS app.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding what the UserDefaults class does. It has no knowledge of the user's settings. It's used for you to save a user's settings (from within your app) persistently.

As for how to access that kind of information. You have to use each of the APIs to check for permissions. For example, access to the GPS requires you to use LocationManager API and check the permission there.

To check if a user has given access to Contacts you have to use the Contacts API ([link here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts))

More specifically [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontactstore/1403143-authorizationstatus) method:

```
class func authorizationStatus(for entityType: CNEntityType) -> CNAuthorizationStatus
```

EDIT:

You should really read on what the UserDefaults class is for. ([link here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults))

Answer (score 0):

You can't use UserDefaults to check whether the user has allowed the app to access Contacts. Try the following code.

```
        let status = CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: CNEntityType.contacts)

        switch (status) {

        // Not determined or restricted (e.g.Parent control)
        case CNAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined,CNAuthorizationStatus.restricted:


        // Denied
        case CNAuthorizationStatus.denied:

        // Allowed
        case CNAuthorizationStatus.authorized:

        }
```

Comment: *"You don't have to use UserDefaults"* - you mean you can't use `UserDefaults`. At least not for these settings.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion.